# error 8085#0: *71722 upstream timed out

Tags: php

currently I am trying to use the Phpmailer for a school project. I do not know a lot about server or nginx. When I use the code for the phpmailer nothing seems to happen, but after a while I get this error allert:

[error] 8085#0: *71722 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 2.203.50.189, server: delivery.nginx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.net, request: "POST /register.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.net", referrer: "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.net"

It would be awesome if someone knows how to fix this problem. 
Thanks alot!!

The code for the phpmailer:

```
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
            require 'vendor/autoload.php';
            //Create a new PHPMailer instance
            //$mailer = new PHPMailer(true);
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            //Set who the message is to be sent from
            $mail->isSMTP();
            //Enable SMTP debugging
            // 0 = off (for production use)
            // 1 = client messages
            // 2 = client and server messages
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
            //Set the hostname of the mail server
            $mail->Host = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
            //Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
            $mail->Port = 587;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
            //Whether to use SMTP authentication
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            //Username to use for SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
            //Password to use for SMTP authentication
            $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
            $mail->setFrom('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx');
            //Set an alternative reply-to address
            //$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
            //Set who the message is to be sent to

            $mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            //Set the subject line
            //$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
            //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert                      referenced images to embedded,
            //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
            //$mail->Body = 'Test';
            $mail->msgHTML("test");
            //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
            //$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
            //Attach an image file
            //$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');
            //send the message, check for errors

            if (!$mail->send()) {
                echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
                echo "Message sent!";
            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

from
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

you must use

port 465 with ssl

or

port 587 with tls

you are currently using ssl with 587

Comment: I solved it myself, it wasn't the code that made the problem. It was the configuration of the server. But still thanks for the reply:)